# Fractional part of $2\sqrt{b^n(b^{n+1}-1)}$ dense in $(0,1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, fractional-part

I'm looking to prove that the fractional parts of the sequence $x_n = 2\sqrt{b^n(b^{n+1}-1)}$ where $n \geq 1$ are dense in $(0,1)$ for all integers $b \geq 2$. I know that each member of the sequence is irrational, since by Catalan's conjecture the product $b^n(b^{n+1}-1)$ is not square. I've tried a few basic arguments, but the sequence seems to grow too quickly.

<s>The sequence $y_n = \log_b 2\sqrt{b^n(b^{n+1}-1)}$ seems better-behaved, since $y_n = n + O(1)$, so it seems easier to prove dense the fractional parts of $y_n$. However, I have no clue whether or not proving that implies $x_n$ is dense.</s> I realized that $y_n$ grows too *slowly*, since it turns out that the fractional part is strictly increasing in $n$ past a certain point, and thus cannot be dense.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If I do not remember bad, what you say is valid for all irrational and a proof is getting using the "principe des tiroirs" (sorry, I can't now using English, it is a very known technique of Dirichlet),

Comment: I think you are referring to the pigeonhole principle? I know that the fractional parts of the integer multiples of any given irrational are dense, and how to prove that. But I do not see how to extend it to this case, since we do not have a fixed irrational.

Comment: It seems similar to proving that $\sqrt b$ is normal in base $b$, that it contains all finite sequences within it.

Comment: @Electro: Exactly! The pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fractional part is not dense when $b$ is a square. Indeed, if $b = j^2$, then

$$x_{n} = 2\sqrt{j^{2n}(j^{2n+2}-1)},$$ which is very slightly smaller than the integer $2j^{2n+1}$. In fact,

$$
\begin{aligned}
0 < 2j^{2n+1} -2\sqrt{j^{2n}(j^{2n+2}-1)}
&= \frac{(2j^{2n+1} -2\sqrt{j^{2n}(j^{2n+2}-1)})(2j^{2n+1} +2\sqrt{j^{2n}(j^{2n+2}-1)})}{2j^{2n+1} +2\sqrt{j^{2n}(j^{2n+2}-1)}}\\
&= \frac{4j^{2n}}{2j^{2n+1} +2\sqrt{j^{2n}(j^{2n+2}-1)}}\\
&=\frac{2}{j + \sqrt{j^2-j^{-2n}}}\\
&< 1.
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus, if $b$ is a square, then $\{x_{n}\}$ is strictly increasing, and furthermore $\{x_{n}\} \rightarrow 1 - 1/j$.

Comment: Oh, thank you! That is quite surprising to me, but it also might explain some other observations. I don't suppose you have any insight into the case of $b$ nonsquare? Or suspect that any other classes behave similarly?

Comment: Ah, whoops, yes, $\{x_n\}$ should be increasing. But not approaching 1. The above difference approaches $1/j$, and since $2j^{2n+1}$ is a bigger integer, we have  $\{x_n\} = 1 - (2j^{2n+1} -2\sqrt{j^{2n}(j^{2n+2}-1)})$.

Comment: That said, it's not clear to me that the case of odd $n$ is trivial. Could you elaborate? I've been fiddling with it for a bit, but no luck.

Comment: Apparently, it is not trivial...my bad.

Comment: But this problem is related to studying whether $\{ \sqrt{b}^{n}\}$ is dense modulo $1$.